# Morning blessings without Tefillin, Tallit, or Tzitzit

Tags: halacha, tefilin, tzitzis, tallit-gadol

If a person doesn't have Tallit, Tzitzit, or Tefillin, does a person say the morning blessings regarding them during Shacharit?

Comment: What would be the rationale to say "...להתעטף בציצית" when one isn't wrapping himself in a tallit? Same goes for the others. Rule is: "all blessings for mitzvot are recited before their performance" (BT Pes. 7b).

Comment: @Oliver I'm not sure that adage is universally true regarding *Birkot Hashachar*. As I understand, one says *Al Netilat Yadayim* even if one did not wash his hands in the morning. Likewise, *Asher Yatzar* is said even if one did not use the rest room.

Comment: @DanF You are right to the extent that some (unfortunately -IMHO- many) recite those 2 blessings in shul, but 1) it's not so halachically preferred, and more importantly 2) those can be classified as birchot ha'shvach.

Comment: Which morning blessings regard Tallit, Tzitzit or Tefillin? "Oter Yisrael beTifarah"?

Answer (score 3):

Not all the morning blessings are said every morning.

Those that thank Gcd for awakening from sleep, like Elokuy Neshomo, are skipped if one didn't sleep.

Asher Yotzar is not said if one didn't go to the bathroom.

Blessing for Tallit, Tzitzit and Tefillin are said when one puts them one. If one doesn't put them one then one can't say them. For example, On Tisha B'Av we skip the Brachot for Tallit and Tefillin in the morning and only say them at Mincha, since we only put on Tallit and Tefillin at Mincha.

Source: Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 7.

Comment: Fyi some say to say asher yatzar in the morning even if one didn't use the restroom, although the MB recommends using the restroom first.